# what's the issue with this application deployment in iOS4.1?

Tags: iphone, deployment

When we gave our app for ad-hoc testing, our tester reported that the app could not be installed because iTunes gave the error "resources have been modified". Please note that the app installed fine previously with the same procedures which we implement for deploying apps during ad-hoc. The only difference is that the device used for testing has its OS upgraded from 4.0 to 4.1 and now we are unable to install the app.

There are no issues with the zipped application file sent, no Thumbs.db file is present to corrupt the .app folder and all the distribution profiles are in place.

Also, we found out that the base SDK for building this app is 3.0, which installs fine in iOS 3.1.3 and 4.0 but gives issues with 4.1

One other app which has been written with base SDK 3.1.3 deploys correctly in iOS 4.1 though.

Please suggest some workarounds for this deployment issue

Answer (score 0):

This is because someone has modified the files in the .app folder. If people go into the .app folder Thumbs.db will be created automatically, or they may have modified/changed something else.

Try rebuilding the file and zip it into a folder called "Payload.zip" then change this name to "yourAppName.ipa". This will stop people from being able to modify the files in the .app folder.

Comment: agreed that the .app folder should not be tampered with, but the same .app folder works for version 4.0 and not 4.1, we will try as you have suggested though

Comment: fair enough. :) have a look see what you can do :)

Comment: is it compulsory that for installing .ipa files we need to jailbreak our iPhone? We do not intend to jailbreak the device and we are unable to find a documented way to install .ipa files in Apple's website

Comment: drag and drop them into itunes... all apps are in .ipa format - except on a Mac it is possible to just install the .app. :)